Selecting Underlayment and Waterproofing for Mosaic Tile in Bathroom Floor
TL;DR: I'd like some advice on the best option for underlayment layers to apply between subfloor and <2 inch mosaic tile (pictured). Our original (probably silly) plan was DITRA - but that doesn't seem feasible due to tile size limits upon further reading. Want to minimize additional height as much as reasonably possible. Thank you!
Current situation in bathroom
Tile we are planning to use

Hello! My wife and I are renovating a bathroom in our 1950s house, and have completed demo down to the plank subfloor. Added some Advantech 3/4 OSB to provide some more consistent strength to the existing subfloor, which was frankly in good shape, and quite level (not 100%, but damn near). I'm now researching a waterproofing plan b, as my original method of DITRA membrane application seems risky as we are utilizing a mosaic tile for the floor (note: not a shower floor, there will be a tub installed otherwise).
I see some conflicting information and a few options upon further research:

DITRA being actually viable with a layer of kerdi membrane on top
after filling with thinset: to me that feels needlessly expensive
and likely still suboptimal application of DITRA (although, I'd
rather pay a bit more not to tear this up soon due to failure of
waterproofing or tile pops. Money is not my primary concern as we're
saving some by not hiring this out.
Kerdi membrane over the whole floor: I know that Kerdi doesn't
recommend application outside of the shower/tub area, so I feel this
is also not the best..
Liquid Membrane - Laticrete Hydro BAN and Laticrete Membrane Roll for corners - This feels time consuming but maybe my best option?
RedGard All over the floor before thinset and tile?

All in all, really just wanting to do this right and avoid future problems from incorrect installation of the next layers prior to tiles. Would really appreciate any advice from you all on the "full stack" of layers between my OSB plywood and this mosaic tile to minimize additional height and achieve a waterproof bathroom floor outside the tub. Thank you!
